# Android AppCompat ActionBar 2xHeight

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-actionbar-compat

I have a view which has a TabLayout in it. But the action bar is twice the height that it normally is.

I don't know if this is related to the TabLayout. The other views in the app which do not have a tabLayout, the action bar is the correct height

Has anyone experienced this? and if so what was the solution?

Here is a cut down version of my view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabFrame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    local:tabMode="fixed"
    local:tabGravity="fill"
    style="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Update - I have since removed all the TabLayout code, and the ActionBar is still double the height it should be. I'm completely stumped on this one.

I can only think this has something to do with InvalidateOptionsMenu. I have tried changing it to use SupportInvalidateOptionsMenu.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted. Can the person give their reason

Comment: Have you try with custom style instead of `@style/Them.AppCompat`? like `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>`

Comment: What would affect the height of the action bar? I will try this tomorrow

Comment: Maybe you've include Toolbar in your layout so the height of action bar is not really the action bar but action bar + toolbar. Then you don't need to use actioBar in your style.

Comment: No I have no toolbar in the layout. The strange thing is I have taken out all the tab layout from the layout and the code and the action bar is still 2x the correct size

Comment: clean and rebuild your project first.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in one of our base classes it was deciding whether the action was a tabbed mode or a navigation mode. I needed to remove the code which set it as the tabbed mode.